# How to get element value in xpath

Tags: xpath

I am trying to get an XML element value out of a string but is doesn't work yet.

Normally i only extract the xpath text values but now i want to get the EAN code of the following string:

```
 <div data-retailrocket-markup-block="60c8602d97a528373cb51d77" data-product-id="8710429017146"></div>
```

Is this possible? And if so how? Thanks a lot!

Comment: the ean code is shown in the data-product-id tag.

Comment: /div/@data-product-id

Comment: @oldprogrammer: it doesn't work yet. But maybe because the code is invisible for the frontend. The full page: https://shorturl.at/gsw68

Comment: i cannot delete the answer. But do you know how i can tackle this one?